# vb.net run powershell script from a windows service

Tags: vb.net, powershell, windows-services

I made a desktop app that create a ps1 file and then execute it through powershell, and it's working fine. I need to convert it to a windows service, all is working until the creation of the ps1 script, that is correctly saved to the parent folder, but it is never executed because, I guess, it's not so simple to launch powershell from within the service itself.
This is what I do in the desktop app to run the script:

```
Dim attivaOutput As New ProcessStartInfo("%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe", "-noexit -WindowStyle hidden -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file """ & fileName & "")
Process.Start(attivaOutput)
```

How can I accomplish this from the windows service? Thanks

Comment: Your string concatenation is wrong. You are inserting a literal double-quote before the file name but not after. This is why you should not use string concatenation like that: it's hard to read and thus error-prone. You should use `String.Format` or string interpolation. It doesn't guarantee you won't mess it up but it makes it less likely. This is also why you should actually look at the string your code creates, not just the code that creates it, to make sure it is what it's supposed to be. You should have picked that up yourself long before posting here.

Comment: @jmcilhinney As I said the script that is produced by this code is working fine (it produce a working and tested powershell script), it's not wrong and that's not the point of the question. The point is that the script is executed by desktop app but the same is not executed by windows service (through powershell) so I'm wondering if powershell works within services. Thank you anyway for your off topic comment

Comment: The code `"-noexit -WindowStyle hidden -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file """ & fileName & ""` would literally create a string like this: `-noexit -WindowStyle hidden -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file "FileNameHere`. How can that possibly be correct, whether or not it produces the desired results? I find it very hard to believe that you wanted a double-quote before the file name but not after. What the point of the question was is not relevant to what the point of my comment was.

Comment: @jmcilhinney actually it produce -noexit -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file ""FileNameHere and for some reason it works just like that, I just tried it multiple times. If I change how quotes are it doesn't work anymore. Still it's not the point of the question, my issue is that powershell won't run if launched by windows service. Have you any hint on that? Thanks

Comment: To avoid further complaining I've just changed the code to Dim attivaOutput As New ProcessStartInfo("powershell", "-noexit -WindowStyle hidden -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file " & Chr(34) & completePath & Chr(34)), it's working just like before in desktop app and not working as before in windows service.